Not getting cookie when hosting my website
Issue with retrieving current user token when website is hosted, but works fine on localhost
Backend Code (Node.js / Express):

indexController.js:
Includes the 'currentUser' and 'signin' functions which handle retrieving the current user
router.js:
Defines the routes for '/signin' and '/user'.
sendtoken.js:
Contains the 'sendToken' function responsible for sending the token to the client.

Frontend Code (Redux):
Redux actions for fetching current user data and signing in users.
Issue: When I try to sign in or retrieve the current user's data on the hosted website unable to retrieve the token for currentuser function.
This is my indexController.js
exports.currentUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.id).exec()
  res.json({ user })
})

exports.signin = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).select("+password").exec()
  if (!user)
    return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found with this email address", 404))
  const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(req.body.password)
  if (!isPasswordMatched)
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Wrong Credentials", 401))
  sendToken(user, 200, res)
})

This is router.js
router.post('/signin', signin)

router.post('/user', isAuthenticated, currentUser)

sendtoken.js
exports.sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = user.getjwttoken()
  const options = {
    exipres: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
    secure:true
  }
  console.log(token)
  res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options)
    .json({ success: true, id: user._id,token })
}

Redux Code
export const asyncCurrentUser = (token) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/user");

    if (response && response.data && response.data.user) {
        console.log(response)
        dispatch(saveUser(response.data.user));
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid response format from server:', response.data);
    }

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching current user data:', error.response?.data ||error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const asyncsigninUser = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/signin", user);
    console.log(response.data.token)
    if (response.status == 200) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token)
      await dispatch(asyncCurrentUser(response.data.token))
    }

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    throw error;
  }
};


On Redux
Here I think you should use {withCredentials: true} while making a request with axios to save the token in cookies.
So in your case
const response = await axios.post("/user",{withCredentials: true});

// ...do that with other requests

Also, I recommend you make it a GET request instead of a POST request.
router.post('/user', isAuthenticated, currentUser)

